# archive.ubuntu.com connection failed.. all other repositories( Elementary and other ppas) working

Tags: updates, release-hera

I am new to linux. I have been using elementary OS for about 15 days now. Everything was fine until few days ago when suddenly I could not connect to ubuntu repositories.

- Using the "select best server" in softwares & updates does not work
- Manually adding ubuntu repositories with sudo add-apt-repository does not work.

The following is the result of sudo apt update.

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**But if I ping 91.189.88.149, I get reply.**

Comment: Can you please update your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is still the same. I cant install applications from ubuntu mirrors. I am getting by downloading the packages form packages.ubuntu.net. Can the recent upgrade to 5.1 Hera be the cause??

Comment: Update: This problem has been fixed by changing the ubuntu mirror.
I replaced the sources.list default entry with that of my country http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted, and then everything is well.
But I am confused why I can not download from ubuntu main archives. I can download some but not all form main archives. And as in my question, I get ping reply.